# Is it possible to create category for only one site in a multisite setup?

Tags: craft3, categories, multi-site

If not, how would you best approach this issue?

For us, different sites have different categories, and also, not always the same number of categories.

At the moment, when we create a category, it gets created for all sites and only thing we can do is rename it on different sites.

If we delete a category from one site, it gets deleted on all sites.

Only solution that I can think of at the moment, is to have all categories created on all sites. In backend, all categories would be visible and available on all sites. On frontend we would just display only those categories which have entries in them, per site.

But we are talking about a lot of categories here, it would be messy.

Any better solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this was originaly scheduled for Craft 3.2 (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2122) this was not in the 3.2 release. Brandon mentioned on Discord ([link](https://discordapp.com/channels/456442477667418113/456442477667418115/575506608952442891?utm_campaign=Craft%2BLink%2BList&utm_medium=web&utm_source=Craft_Link_List_88)) that categories will be going away altogether in Craft 4.0:

Here is his [comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoeCX.png):

> tags and categories are both going away in Craft 4.
>   3.x (maybe as early as 3.2) will see a big update to Entries fields, where they will be able to behave more like current Categories and
>   Tags fields, if desired and 4.0 will just convert all existing
>   categories & tags over to entries

So as it stand, I wouldn't use categories anymore and use structures instead.